# PHP Tools and Visual Studio swedish characters in output window

Tags: php, visual-studio

Is there a way to get Swedish characters in the output window? I have tried different settings under Options.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40783

Comment: I have tried this also, it´s says allready installed! The Visual Studio has swedish characters, but the output windows (after you run Run without debuggning) does not show swedish characters, The Developer CMD is showing swedish charachters as well the ordinary cmd. /Mats